# how to setup auto-close for popup in framework7 version1

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

i am using a framwork7 js version 1 for my android mobile app.but there is a problem in login popup, after the successful login the router is working, but the popup is still on the screen, it is not close.

index file popup code

```
<div class="popup popup-login">
    <div class="content-block">
        <h4>LOGIN</h4>
        <div class="loginform">
            <form id="LoginForm" method="post" class="close-panel">
                 <div  id="msgprint" style="display: block;"></div>
                <input type="text" name="Username" id="username" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="Password" id="password" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="Password" />

                <input type="button" name="submit" class="form_submit" id="submitlogin" onclick="loginHost()" value="SIGN IN" />
            </form>
            <div class="signup_bottom"> 
                <p>Don't have an account?</p>
                <a href="#" data-popup=".popup-signup" class="open-popup">SIGN UP</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="close_popup_button">
            <a href="#" class="close-popup"><img src="images/icons/black/menu_close.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript for the router page

```
if(response.data.is_success){
    mainView.router.loadPage({url:'user-product.html', ignoreCache:true, 
    reload:true });

}
```

if anyone knows the solutions. please answer.

Comment: add this code before calling product page myApp.closeModal(); and try

Comment: thank very much @prasannaputtaswamy puttaswamy.that is work. myApp.closeModal('.popup-login');